# Canvas.clipRegion(Region region) deprecated

Tags: java, android, android-canvas

In my Android project, I've updated my project to API 26, but now the function Canvas.clipRegion(Region region) is no longer there. can anyone help me with this? what function must I use now in place of clipRegion.

```
public boolean clipRegion(@NonNull final Region region, @NonNull final Op op) {
        region.translate(xOffset, yOffset);
        return mCanvas.clipRegion(region, op);
    }
```

Comment: Some combination of clipPath, clipRegion, and clipOutPath/clipOutRegion.  You don't give us enough data of what you're trying to do to give a better answer.

Comment: I think clip is deprecated cause Hardware_accelerated didnt supported it for a long time, maybe never will.

You can try to find how to clip your polygons instead of the canvas.

Answer (score 1):

In the documentation [Canvas](https://developer.android.com/sdk/api_diff/26/changes/android.graphics.Canvas.html). They mention that clipRegion method is removed not deprecated. Instead of use **clipOutPath**  method. For more info please refer the link.